# $B_0(\mathcal{N},\mathcal{B})$ is Banach - The hypothesis of $\mathcal{B}$ being Banach cannot be removed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, compact-operators

I am studying the book cited, particularly this Theorem:

> The space   $B_0(\mathcal{N},\mathcal{B})$ of the compact operators (including those that have finite post) is Banach.

The hypothesis of $\mathcal{B}$ being complete cannot be removed and for the study the author build a counterexample using $B(\mathcal{B_1},\mathcal{N_1})$, where

$$\mathcal{B_1}=C^1[0,1]$$ with norm $$|||\psi|||=||\psi||_\infty+||\psi'||_\infty$$

and

$$\mathcal{N_1}=C^1[0,1]$$ with norm $$||\psi||_\infty$$.

At certain point the author states that, for $|||\psi|||\leq 1$, we have $$|\psi(t)-\psi(s)|\leq|t-s|$$ for all $t,s\in[0,1]$.

I could not understand why.

Many thanks.

==========

*OLIVEIRA, César de. **Introdução à Análise Funcional**. Rio de Janeiro: Impa, 2012. (Projeto Euclides).*

Comment: If $|||\psi||| \leq 1$, then $\|\psi’\|_{\infty} \leq |||\psi||| \leq 1$ thus $\psi$ is $1$-Lipschitz.

Comment: Great, many thanks.